# PySpark ML Jaccard Similarity

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataset that has a `Cust_ID`, and `Item_id`. Essentially the Customer basket for each customer. I am trying to implement Jaccard similarity using Minhash LSH as below and get an

> errorcannot import name 'MinHashLSH'

Code:

```python
from pyspark.ml.feature import MinHashLSH
dfDetailSelvect = dfDetailSel.rdd.map(lambda x: Row(label=x[0],features=DenseVector(x[1].toArray())) if (len(x)>1 and hasattr(x[1], "toArray")) else Row(label=None, features=DenseVector([])))

mh = MinHashLSH(inputCol="features", outputCol="hashes", numHashTables=5) model = mh.fit(dfDetailSelvect)
```

Comment: which version of spark are you using?

Comment: I am using Spark 2.1.0 on Azure

Comment: MinHashLSH feature is available in spark 2.2.0+(experimental).

Comment: Thanks for the help!